# How do I properly set $scope properties from services that return a promise?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I am trying to figure out the proper way to set properties in my controller's $scope when those properties must be retrieved from some service. Typically I assign scope variables as follows:

```
$scope.firstName = 'John';
$scope.lastName = 'Doe';
```

So how do I perform the same operation when I want to retrieve the property value from some service method?

Here is my factory service method:

```
var getUserDetails = function () {
    return $q.when($resource('/api/v1/common/userdetails').get());
};
```

I would like to assign user details in my controller's $scope like so:

```
$scope.userDetails = commonService.getUserDetails();
```

However, that does not work. I end up having to do something like this which feels very unnatural:

```
commonService.getUserDetails().then(function (user) {
     $scope.user = user;
});
```

Not to mention the above will return a promise, not just the pure user data result I would like. I feel as though I'm not using promises, services, or assigning scope values from services in my controller appropriately.

Can someone please let me know if this is correct, and if not please show the proper way to do this?

Comment: That is how promises work, if your using a router you may wan't to use resolve depending on your situation/usecase... It all depends on how the app/page should work

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the answers $resource still does what you expect it to - although automatic unwrapping was removed from promises it still works with `$resource`. The problem is that you explicitly wrapped it in a regular $q promise when you called `$q.when` on it. Instead, do:

```
var getUserDetails = function () {
    return $resource('/api/v1/common/userdetails').get(); // no $q.when
};
```

And you will get the behavior you're expecting:

```
$scope.userDetails = commonService.getUserDetails(); // will work.
```

Although personally - I like the explicit notation that doesn't hide the fact an http request is being made better.